Icecast status page not showing Server Name, Server Description, Stream Name, or Stream Description
I have PHP streaming MP3 files listed in playlist.txt to Icecast using FFMpeg.
$ffmpeg_command = "ffmpeg -re -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i /var/www/html/media/radio/playlist.txt -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp3 -ice_name \"My Name\" -ice_description \"My Description\" -metadata title=\"My Title\" -metadata artist=\"My Artist\" -metadata genre=\"My Genre\" -headers \"Icy-MetaData: 1\" icecast://source:Password@99.99.99.99:8000/stream > /dev/null 2>&1 &";

The stream plays correctly, but the Admin and Public status pages for Icecast show the Server Name, Server Description, Stream Name, and Stream Description as "Unspecified".
I've checked my Icecast XML file. It seems to have all the relevant sections as follows...
<icecast>     
<server-name>My Server Name</server-name>
<server-description>My Server Description</server-description>
...
<metadata-update-interval>10</metadata-update-interval>
...
<limits>
    ...
    <metadata>1</metadata
</limits>
...
<mount>
   <mount-name>/stream</mount-name>
   <name>My Name</name>
   <description>My Description</description>
   <genre>My Genre</genre>    
   ...
   <public>1</public>
</mount>
...
<fileserve>1</fileserve>
...
</icecast>

The genre tag is passed from the XML file to the Admin and Public status pages. But the server-name and server-description tags in the global icecast tag are not.
-ice_name, -ice_description and -metadata tags are not being passed from FFMpeg to the Icecast status pages, despite me including them along with -headers "Icy-MetaData: 1" in the FFMpeg command.
metadata-update-interval and metadata tags are present in the Icecast XML file.
What am I doing wrong?

Do you need to have a <mount> section in your config for some reason?  Usually you can just skip that and the mount will be automatically created when you connect the source.  I don't remember which takes precedence in terms of name/description/genre/etc.  Also, you don't need -headers \"Icy-MetaData: 1\", that's only used on the client side for listening.  Can you change your app to log the FFmpeg STDOUT/STDERR and see if there are any errors?
